# How can I display all data from Firestore documents into an html table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing a web page that will obtain data from my firestore collection and display each document with its corresponding fields Here is the code:

```
<table class="table is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>AR Level</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is the JS:

```
db.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book").where("Program", "==", "AR")
.get()
.then(
    function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            dataObj = doc.data()
            console.log(dataObj)
            buildTable(dataObj)
            function buildTable(data){
                var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var row = `<tr>
                                    <td>${data[i].Title}</td>
                                    <td>${data[i].Author}</td>
                                    <td>${data[i].Points}</td>
                              </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row
                }
            }
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Hi, the data is not being displayed. No error message. Later on I realized that the data is not i order. So thats why I came to stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you're using a for loop in your function. Unless one "Book" document is an Array of items each having the Title/Author/Points fields.

You're basically looping through the data object as if it's an array. Chances are, it's not.

If I'm right, and one "Book" document is object/map containing those three fields, then your code should be like this:

```
db.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book").where("Program", "==", "AR")
.get()
.then(querySnapshot=>{
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            let data = doc.data();
            let row  = `<tr>
                            <td>${data.Title}</td>
                            <td>${data.Author}</td>
                            <td>${data.Points}</td>
                      </tr>`;
            let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            table.innerHTML += row
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    });
```