# How to retrieve an array from Firestore and output it onto an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array with multiple objects in it. I would like to output the objects onto an HTML page

[image: array with objects]

The image above is how the array is structured. There is an array called reserved items and it has objects in it. I would like to output all the objects in this array, specifically the "Title" element.

here is what i tried:

```
let query;
    if (lastReservedBook != null) {
        query = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid).startAfter(lastReservedBook)
    } else {
        query = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid);
    }
    
    query.limit(100).get().then(querySnapshot=>{
    
        lastReservedBook = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            console.log(doc.data())
            let data = doc.data();
            let row  = `<tr>
                                    <td><a onclick="barcode=${data.Barcode}; myFunction(this)">${data.reserved_items}</a></td>
                                    
                            </tr>`;
            let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            table.innerHTML += row
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none"
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display all data from Firestore documents into an html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471567/how-can-i-display-all-data-from-firestore-documents-into-an-html-table)

Comment: Hi could you please have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231789/how-to-retrieve-an-array-from-cloud-firestore-and-output-it-onto-an-html-table